# Proper owner of var/www/html

Tags: apache, permissions

I am running apache2 in Ubuntu 14.04.  I have been having trouble with permissions with FTP clients and CMS that use backend FTP.  I never seem to be able to get the permissions right.  Should www-data be the owner of /var/www/html and root as a user assigned to that group?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Some CMSes and Wordpress is especially bad about that because it's actually in the code to use the web user.

BTW you should never need to use `root` for ftp. `www-data` the default apache user on ubuntu should own your web files/directory to work properly with many cmses.

So this is what has worked before and what we did for clients with the same issue. chown the whole web root as `www-data` for both `user and group`.

So if your document root is `/var/www/html`, cd or change directory to `/var/www` and run this to change ownership on all files and directories.

```
chown -R www-data: html/
```

while still in the `/var/www` directory add write permissions to the group for files and directories by running this command.

```
find html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} + -o -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

Finally add your FTP user to the `www-data` group.

```
usermod -a -G www-data username
```

Replace usename with your FTP client username

Now this setup should allow you to use manage files and still allow the CMS ftp backend to still function and write to the direc. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Well, that answers my question but it didn't fix my problem.  This is what  get when attempting to install Drupal for a client.  "The directory sites/default/files does not exist. An automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the installer has the permissions to create it automatically."

Comment: Found the problem.  When I am working on things directly from my desktop,  if I need to add things to the web folders I tend to do it as a super user in nautilus but the problem with that is that the owner of those files ends up being that user rather than www-data.

Comment: @PanamaJack,I suggest another solution:`chown -R root: html/`,then `find html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} + -o -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +`.it's unavailing that set owner to other user.Do you agree?

Comment: Owning the files by `www-data` isn't dangerous?  See <https://askubuntu.com/a/873841>

Answer (score -4):

This command worked for me:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) your_folder_name
```