# Execute an installed software command on a remote linux server using a PHP page

Tags: php, linux, server, console

I am developing a 3D printing web page. To make the calculations of material and time I am trying to make the web run the cura-engine software (a console program) on the file.

I created a virtual machine in Google Cloud Platform running a LAMP stack under debian 10. I installed the cura'engine package with apt and I can run it from the terminal (via ssh):

```
eduardoj_vieirav@instance-1-vm:/var/www/html$ CuraEngine

Cura_SteamEngine version 3.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Ultimaker

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.
...
```

But when trying to execute this command with php using exec or shell_exec I have no output.

```
<?php
echo exec('CuraEngine');
?>
```

I have also tried to perform the operations on the file and again I can do it from ssh using the command:

```
eduardoj_vieirav@instance-1-vm:/var/www/html$ CuraEngine slice -v -j resources/definitions/creality_ender3.def.json -o gcode/output.gcode -l STL/cube.stl
```

But again it can't be run from php

```
<?php
echo exec('CuraEngine slice -v -j resources/definitions/creality_ender3.def.json -o gcode/output.gcode -l STL/cube.stl');
?>
```

I find it strange that I cannot execute CuraEngine since other commands such as `uname -a0` return output.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same as you. Things I've tried: run CuraEngine from an sh file; and redirecting the terminal output to a file with `CuraEngine -options 2> cura_output`. No luck so far. CuraEngine doesn't run when called with shell_exec. Did you manage to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you have problems with `$PATH` environment variable from PHP. Try to specify absolute path to `CuraEngine` (use `whereis CuraEngine` command if needed).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Lyudmila. `CuraEngine` is installed locally on the virtual machine in `/usr/bin/CuraEngine`. Using the absolute path I also get the same result.

Comment: As I see from manual your program Cura_SteamEngine needs terminal (tty). But when you run the program using exec/shell_exec virtual terminal is not present! You could try to use `--connect` option of Cura to make it work with socket for control instead of tty device.

Comment: I think that's the right direction Lyudmila. Thank you. If I find a solution I will return.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably all due to permissions as I was able to find from many other posts available online.
Try to write this (note the  2>&1 at the end) and the output should indicate if it is a permission error.

```php
<?php
echo exec('CuraEngine slice -v -j resources/definitions/creality_ender3.def.json -o gcode/output.gcode -l STL/cube.stl  2>&1');
?>
```

Afterwards, if it is a permission error apply the ownership changes mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918996/proper-owner-of-var-www-html) post and it should work.